# how to add Sign in and Create account on footer in magento2?

Tags: magento2

How to add sign in and create account on footer in magento2?
Please help me ?

Comment: Hi David, do you want to put those link inside CMS Block?

Answer (score 1):

Please add below 2 links inside your Footer CMS Block.

```
<a href="{{store direct_url="customer/account/login"}}">Sign In</a>
<a href="{{store direct_url="customer/account/create"}}">Create</a>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i have solve it above problem .

Answer (score 1):

Content->Blocks:footer_links_block

Add the below code like:

```
<li class="nav item"><a href="{{store direct_url="customer/account/login"}}">Sign In</a></li>
<li class="nav item"><a href="{{store direct_url="customer/account/create"}}">Create</a></li>
```

Thanks..